# Pidyon Haben with 1 coin

Tags: halacha, pidyon-haben

Can Pidyon HaBen be performed with a single coin in the following manner?

1. Father gives 1 coin to the Kohen
2. Kohen gives the coin as charity to the father

Repeat 3 and a half times

The questions underlying question in my mind are as follows:

1. Can the Kohen do whatever he wants with the coins including giving it away for charity? (I assume yes on this one)
2. Do all the coins need to be given at once? ( I know that 5 coins can be split to 5 Kohanim)
3. Does the Kohen need to hold onto the money until the full amount is
   given?(for example if he loses 1 coin before getting the second)

Comment: How is question 3 relevant to the original question, considering you give it all in one shot?

Comment: Number 3 is really a duplicate of question 2, just asked from a different perspective